# Performing calculations with input variables python3.x

Tags: python

Python will multiply variables if I set the value in my code, e.g
    `wage=10`
    `hours=35`
    `wage*hours`
    `350 #return from python`
However if I define the variables with input, those variables will not multiply, e.g
    `Wage=input ("What is your wage?")`
    `What is your wage?20`
    `Hours=input("How many hours did you work this week?")`
    `How many hours did you work this week?40`
    `Wage*Hours #Here is where the problem is`
At this point python will show an error message:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Is there a way to use input as a variable? The simpler the better as I have no programming experience and am just starting out with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is the input you are receiving is as a string.
What we want is to receive it as an integer so it can be multiplied.

```
Wage = input("What is your wage?")
Wage = int(Wage)

Hours = input("How many hours did you work this week?")
Hours = int(Hours)

Wage*Hours
```

Will return the right value as an integer, the way you want it.

This is not the most efficient of course, just easy to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3.x, `input` function returns strings. So you need to convert the values to `int` explicitly.

This works:

```
Wage=input ("What is your wage?")
Hours=input("How many hours did you work this week?")
print(int(Wage)*int(Hours))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using python3. You need to convert the input to an integer for calculations before using them, as it is mentioned in the raised error. Because the all input values are accepted as strings.

For example you can not do this

```
print("5" + 5)
```

or this

```
print("3" * "4")  # Which is now happening.
```

will give you an error.

Instead, use:

```
Wage = int(input("What is your wage?"))
```

And apply this to other inputs that you want to use in calculations of course.

Answer (score 0):

input returns a string . you should try this and cast variables to `int`:

```
int (wage) * int(hours)
```